# How strong does a light source on the Moon have to be to be visible from Earth?

Tags: the-moon, light, naked-eye

Flashes from some meteoroid impacts on the Moon can be seen with the naked eye. How much light must a future lunar base emit in order to be visible as a dot in the lunar night (like the flag of Tunisia)? I suppose it is a bit complicated and depends on the phase of the Moon, and that the new Moon is so close to the Sun.

[image]

Comment: This is sort of the reverse of this question: Can you see man-made lights on the dark side of the Earth from the surface of the moon with the naked eye? http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8105/can-you-see-man-made-lights-on-the-dark-side-of-the-earth-from-the-surface-of-th/8111#8111 You need 100 megawatts or so to see a non-coherent light source from lunar distance.

Comment: Somewhat related, very amusing http://what-if.xkcd.com/13/