# Sky viewer from the moon

Tags: the-moon

Is there any app or website that is able to view the sky from the moon? It would be like `https://www.timeanddate.com/astronomy/night/` except that it is viewed from the moon

Comment: I believe https://celestia.space/ will do what you want.

Comment: different but related: [How will planets behave in the night sky as seen by Mars colonists?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26166/7982) and [Is there an online planetarium where the observer is on another celestial body?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35938/7982) and [On other planets, does the sun appear to pass through the same zodiac constellations?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/47569/7982) and [When will the next transit of Earth be visible from Mars? Was the last one really on May 11, 1984?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26177/7982)

Comment: and [How does the Earth move in the sky as seen from the Moon?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/8100/7982) Also some of the options discussed in answers to [Where can I find the positions of the planets, stars, moons, artificial satellites, etc. and visualize them?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/13488/7982) can view from a user-definable position.

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of websites or applications.

My usual go-to is Stellarium. Here with Neil Armstrong's possible first view on Earth from the Moon's surface:
[image: Stellarium with observer position set to landing place and time of Apollo 11]